# Issue making an API call to the backend in NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I have these files in my NextJS app. Please note that I am new to `NextJS 13`, and have tried searching online, tutorials to catch up with the new updates, and see if I can resolve this myself, but seems that effort is to no avail.

The endpoint that I am trying to make a request to is as follows `src/app/contact-route/route.js`  with this code:

```
export async function postHandler(req, res) {
    try {
        const { data } = req.body;
        console.log("DATA FROM BCK", data);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data received successfully!' });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'failed to load data' });
    }
}

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
        return postHandler(req, res);
    } else {
        res.status(405).json({ message: 'This method is not allowed' });
    }
}
```

And my contact page `src/app/contact/page.js` file has this in it:

```
export default function Contact() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        fullName: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        message: ""
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        setData(prevData => ({
            ...prevData,
            [name]: value
        }));
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const baseUrl = `/app/contact-route`;
            const response = await fetch(baseUrl, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ data })
            });
            const contactData = await response.json();
            console.log(contactData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div >
                <div>
                    <div >
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div>
                                <label htmlFor="full-name">
                                    Full name
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="full-name"
                                    id="full-name"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    autoComplete="name"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label htmlFor="email">
                                    Email
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    id="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    type="email"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    autoComplete="email"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit">
                                    Submit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The issue I am having is that making a `POST` request to the endpoint `src/app/contact-route/route.js` throws a few errors:

```
⨯ Detected default export in '/Users/path-to-file/src/app/contact-route/route.js'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.
 ⨯ No HTTP methods exported in '/Users/path-to-file/src/app/contact-route/route.js'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
```

and

```
POST http://localhost:3000/app/contact-route 404 (Not Found)
handleSubmit @ page.js:28

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

Can you help me resolve this issue. Much thanks

Comment: The log is pretty clear here: you're not supposed to default exported in route.js, and in app router, methods should be called with the method, i.e GET(), POST(), etc

Comment: See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers

Comment: FYI you probably don't want to use `preventDefault()` on the _change_ event

Comment: @Paul Serre - Thanks for your inputs, very much appreciated.  I did mentioned that I am new to NextJs 13, and open to learn from inputs from folks like you - thanks for the input and resources.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost right!

In next.js 13 API functions name must be one of the http methods (GET, POST, DELETE...)

if you will check you network you will see you git 405 (method not allowed)

just change `export async function postHandler(req, res) {`
to `export async function POST(req, res) {`

to be clear, if you want it to be a get request the function name must be `GET(req,res)`

if you want it to support multiple methods all you need to do is:

```
function ANYNAME(req,res){}

export {ANYNAME as GET, ANYNAME as POST}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. This has helped me in my quest to understand how Nextjs 13 works without spending days reading their docs. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that my friend, it takes some time to understand the differences (i'm still learning) but we will get there